# how to apply validation to dynamically added field to form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have form with two fields and until  those fields are filled with some text  my submit button will be disabled but now if i add third field dynamically angular JS  will not support validation for the third field which is added dynamically.

link https://jsfiddle.net/vikrantkki/zzhgaguz/57/

```
 <button ng-click="adddynamicfield()">add dynamic field<button>        
            <form name="dynamicform" novalidate="true">
            <input type ="text" dynamic-name name="name" ng-model="dynamicform1.name"  required>
            <input type ="text" dynamic-name name="age"  class="age" ng-model="dynamicform1.age" required >
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="dynamicform.$invalid">submit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not compiling the newly added html. You can research on `$compile` and it should solve the issue.

But what I recommend for your case is to use an array to represent the dynamic fields, so you can get the model values more easily.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akzor394/14/)

```
$scope.dynamicFields = [];

$scope.adddynamicfield = function() {
  var index = $scope.dynamicFields.length;
  $scope.dynamicFields.push({
    name: 'field' + index,
    model: '',
    className: 'field',
  });
}
```